# IIS is overriding my response content, if I manually set the Response.StatusCode

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc

#### Problem

when I manually set the `HTTP Status` of my response stream to, say, `404` or `503`, IIS renders up the stock IIS content/view, instead of my custom view.

When I do this with the web development server (AKA. [Cassini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltiDev_Cassini_Web_Server)), it works correctly (that is, my content is displayed and the `response.statuscode` == my entered data).

Is there any way I can override this behaviour?

#### How To Replicate

Make a default ASP.NET MVC1 web application. Add the following route

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{*catchall}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

}
```

Now replace the the HomeController's Index method with...

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok - found the answer. As I expected, IIS is hijacking my non 200 responses. Not sure (ie. I'm not sure if this is the default behaviour OR it's because of a setting one of the team members updated in the machine config, etc...).

Anyways, the key here is tell IIS to *not* handle any non-200 status result resources.

How? Config entry in the web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
    .... snipped other IIS relevant elements ... 
</system.webServer>
```

Now, the key here is `existingResponse="PassThrough"` . That bad boy tells IIS to leave my resources alone if the HTTP status code != 200.

Want more info? Sure: [Read More about this Element on the Official IIS Website](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors).

Comment: ***httpErrors*** is like **Error Pages -> 500 -> Edit Feature Settings -> "Detailed Errors"** ?_http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5_

Comment: aaaahhh..  Good ol' IIS making easy things difficult :)

Comment: It works. You are a life saverrrrrrrrr

Comment: Thank you so much this resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to bypass this is to run the following code in your ASP application:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21271085/238753

Answer (score -2):

Be carefull with that approach in general. You should NOT render a view on 404 status.

- I think when a error status code is returned, IIS returns the status error page that is registered with it - not the output from processing. So, you can put a HTML page there (or a link to an aspx page).
  http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2008/02/13/Enforcing-a-Custom-404-Page-in-ASP.NET.aspx
  has a nice explanation how to set up an error page.
- But that is irrelvant. Quite a number of browsers by default do NOT show that output, but something set in the browser. So, if you rely on people seeing your 404 page - that may not happen. They may see the 404 page that is set up in the browser for them.

Comment: Why shouldn't i be rendering a view on a 404? i want a custom page, and my page might require some logic (instead of a static html error page).

Comment: ecause the MVC model does not integrate with the IIS error page model. That simple. You ahve to go back to the IIS model for that. Register a page URL for the 404 case. Put some dynamic page there - I am not sure whether this actually COULD point back to a MVC url, but it MUSt originate in the 404 page registration.

Comment: Incorrect. Most browsers will render the content of a page returned with a 404 HTTP status. Not all, but most. Also, IIS by default will respect the status code as set by any code in a .NET site, as long as no other modules are overriding that later in the pipeline. See the question author's answer on how that was happening in this case.